# asp.net cookie reading does not functioning (same page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, httpcookie

I have a single page with a button and a textbox.
I was expecting that previous cookie should be read on page load.
just attempting read/write simple example. button should save to cookie the textbox value. and at next opening it should read it. but mycookie is always null. what is wrong with the codes ?
any clue?
(thanks)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            HttpCookie mycookie = Request.Cookies["info"];

        if(mycookie!=null)
        TextBox1.Text=mycookie["mytext"];

    }

    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie mycookie= new HttpCookie("info");
        mycookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);

        mycookie["mytext"]=TextBox1.Text;


        Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use the Value property.  Try this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


        HttpCookie mycookie = Request.Cookies["info"];

    if(mycookie!=null)
    TextBox1.Text=mycookie.Value;

}

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie mycookie= new HttpCookie("info");
    mycookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);

    mycookie.Value=TextBox1.Text;


    Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie);
}
```

Comment: I will try. but It wont work because mycookie is already null. when an object is null we cant access any property because object does not exists.

Comment: in Page_Load, we are checking for null.  In LinkButton1_Click, we are instantiating mycookie so it is not null.

Comment: now I transferred project from visual studio 2010 to 2013.
both code worked. but
both code doesnt working on asp.net 2010 but worked on visual studio 2013. interesting.

Comment: interestingly both code working on visual 2013. but on 2010 it doesnt working. mycookie (in page_load) always null on VS2010.

Comment: I dont know how can I tell to my students that solution.they are using vs2010 at school laboratory. so it wont work for them. than Im passing this cookie issue.

Comment: Use fiddler to see that the cookie is coming/going